# Training decision tree with biased data set

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I'm new to data mining and I'm trying to train decision tree, but the data set I've chosen is very biased therefore the result that I am getting is also biased. I've searched online and I came across with balanced accuracy. I'm not satisfied with the result.

Will it be a good idea if I sample my data set in such a way that I proportion it equally, as in 1000 cases of `YES` and 1000 of `NO`?

Comment: Instead of resampling the data set, I'd use weights during training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle class imbalance is to undersample the larger class so that the class distribution is approximately half and half.

Answer of your question is yes, provided 1000 is the size of smaller class so that you lose less larger-class data points.

**Note:** While selecting from larger-class data points, try to leave out those data points which have more missing values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give weightage while modelling. you can assign higher weight to minority class it will compensate the imbalance.